# Hybrid expression that counts number rows with condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 4 tables:

```
class Cebola(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cebolas'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


class Checklist(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'checklists'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    checklist_type = Column(String)
    cebola_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('cebolas.id'))
    cebola = relationship('Cebola', backref=backref('checklists'))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': checklist_type,
                       'polymorphic_identity': 'generic'}


class ChecklistA(Checklist):
    __tablename__ = 'checklist_a'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('checklists.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    notes = Column(Unicode)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'a'}


class ChecklistB(Checklist):
    __tablename__ = 'checklist_b'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('checklists.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    notes = Column(Unicode)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'b'}
```

Now I need a way (probably a hybrid property) that will tell me how many checklists I have in a Cebola with `notes <> ''`.

I have added:

```py
class Cebola(Base):

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_comments(self):
        return len([c for c in self.checklists if c.notes])

    @number_of_comments(cls)
    def number_of_comments(cls):
        ???
```

I have found a similar problem in [SQLAlchemy - Writing a hybrid method for child count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640298/sqlalchemy-writing-a-hybrid-method-for-child-count), but my example is a bit more complex.

Comment: And how would you like to handle `Checklist` generic instances which do not have `notes` property?

Comment: @van they can be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should get you started:

```
class Cebola(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cebolas'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_comments(self):
        # return len([c for c in self.checklists if c.notes])
        # @NOTE:1: below will prevent error for those that do not have `notes` column
        # @NOTE:2: in any case this may issue a lot of SQL statements to load all subclasses of checklists relationship, so is not really efficient
        return len([c for c in self.checklists
                    if hasattr(c, 'notes') and c.notes])

    @number_of_comments.expression
    def number_of_comments(cls):
        from sqlalchemy import select
        ce, cl, cla, clb = [
            _.__table__ for _ in (Cebola, Checklist, ChecklistA, ChecklistB)]
        s = (
            select([func.count(cl.c.id).label("number_of_comments")])
            .select_from(cl.outerjoin(cla).outerjoin(clb))
            .where(or_(cla.c.notes != None, clb.c.notes != None))
            .where(cl.c.cebola_id == cls.id)
            .correlate(cls)
            .as_scalar()
        )
        return s
```

Usage in a query:

```
q = session.query(Cebola, Cebola.number_of_comments)
for cebola, number_of_comments in q.all():
    print(cebola, number_of_comments)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have just a doubt about the usage of session in the hybrid expression. How I can get it if there is no instance of the object yet?

Comment: You are right, using `session` in the hybrid expression is not the right thing to do. I just had a simple query to do this job using `with_polymorphic` (which makes all these nice `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s for you). But you can construct the same expression using expressions directly.

Comment: Updated answer using only expressions without Query instance, which will product the same query. Depending on the database and number of tables, you could even move the `where` clauses to part of `join` conditions, as on some databases it might be faster.

Comment: Thanks! Who would have thought that it is so easy ;)