# Flask Sqlalchemy ORM how to add a property to return the count of child

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

This has been driving me crazy and I'm sure it is more straight forward than I'm making it. But so far, no end of searching and trying various combinations, has failed to get me anywhere.

I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy and I'm new to both..
So, if i have two classes/tables defined like this

```
class Child(db.Modal):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    kidsname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=False)

class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent', lazy=True)
```

What I want is to be able to add a property to the parent class to return the number of children e.g.

```
def child_count(self):
    return ????
```

I would like to be able to do something like this when an instance of parent is passed though to my html template..

```
<p>Parent: {{ parent.name }}  # of children: {{parent.child_count}}</p>
```

Any help or pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `column_property` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property
from sqlalchemy import select, func


class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent', lazy=True)
    child_count = column_property(select([func.count(children.id)]).\
        where(children.parent_id==id))
```

Also, you can find a solution to your problem with the hybrid_property in this question [SQLAlchemy - Writing a hybrid method for child count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640298/sqlalchemy-writing-a-hybrid-method-for-child-count)

Comment: Thank you, There is a missing closing ) but other than that this does work.
Do you know whether this could also be accomplished using @hybrid_property?

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that link but the reason I couldnt get it to work was because my child and parent weren't linked. doh!
Both approaches work now.
Is one a better option over the other and if so why?

Comment: I am not sure what is a better option for your problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. 
```child_count = column_property(select([func.count(children.id)]).\
        where(children.parent_id==id))```
In the above line I am getting error 
```
File "...\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 949, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 923, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: id
```
In the func.count, does "children" refers to the property in the parent?