# hybrid_property "is_parent" on self referencial one-to-many parent-child model in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a self referential model with a one-to-many parent-children relationship. The model instances can be linked to a parent instance, which will then form part of an observation group, with the `observation_id` for each child and the parent being the group's parent `id`. This `observation_id` is a hybrid_property of the model. I'd like to add a few `hybrid_property` expressions to enable filtering on these hybrid properties, but I am stuck with the `is_parent` expression definition. Here's an excerpt of the model:

```python
class AnnotationLabel(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'annotation'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    parent_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("annotation.id", ondelete="CASCADE", nullable=True, index=True)
    parent = relationship('AnnotationLabel', remote_side='AnnotationLabel.id', 
        backref=backref('children', passive_deletes=True, lazy='dynamic'))

    @hybrid_property
    def is_child(self):
        """BOOLEAN, whether or not this annotation has a linked parent annotation"""
        return self.parent_id is not None

    @is_child.expression
    def is_child(cls):
        return cls.parent_id.isnot(None)

    @hybrid_property
    def is_parent(self):
        """BOOLEAN, whether or not this annotation has linked children / descendants"""
        return self.children.count() > 0

    @is_parent.expression
    def is_parent(cls):
        # TODO: this does not work. 
        q = select([func.count(cls.id)]).where(cls.parent_id==cls.id)
        print(q)  # debug
        return q.as_scalar() > 0

    @hybrid_property
    def observation_id(self):
        """INT, denoting the observation group id for linked observations of the same object (returns None if not linked)"""
        return self.id if self.is_parent else self.parent_id if self.is_child else None

    @observation_id.expression
    def observation_id(cls):
        # TODO: this may work if is_parent.expression was fixed? But haven't had a chance to test it
        return db.case([(cls.is_child, cls.parent_id), (cls.is_parent, cls.id)], else_=None)
```

Currently the `@is_parent.expression` always seems to evaluate to false. The SQL that is generated in the expression attribute (based on the debug print in the example above) appears to be something like this:

```sql
SELECT count(annotation.id) AS count_1 FROM annotation WHERE annotation.parent_id = annotation.id
```

Which should never really occur, since an instance would not normally be its own parent, but rather the parents of other instances, and consequently, when filtering on that, it always returns nothing. Eg:

```python
printfmt="ID: {a.id}, parent_id: {a.parent_id}, observation_id: {a.observation_id}, is_parent: {a.is_parent}, is_child: {a.is_child}"  # instance print formatter

# THIS WORKS - returns the two child instances
for a in AnnotationLabel.query.filter(AnnotationLabel.is_child==True).all():
    print(printfmt.format(a=a))
# ID: 837837, parent_id: 837838, observation_id: 837838, is_parent: False, is_child: True
# ID: 837909, parent_id: 837838, observation_id: 837838, is_parent: False, is_child: True

# THIS WORKS, PARENT INSTANCE HAS CORRECT PROPERTIES
parent = AnnotationLabel.query.get(837838)   # get the parent in question
# This works, since it's using the instance attributes
print(printfmt.format(a=parent))
# ID: 837838, parent_id: None, observation_id: 837838, is_parent: True, is_child: False

# THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!??? .expression for is_parent is broken
for a in AnnotationLabel.query.filter(AnnotationLabel.is_parent==True).all():
    print(printfmt.format(a=a))
# returns nothing, should be list containing 1 parent instance

# THIS ALSO DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY - ONLY RETURNS CHILDREN, NOT PARENT
for a in AnnotationLabel.query.filter(AnnotationLabel.observation_id==837838).all():
    print(printfmt.format(a=a))
# ID: 837837, parent_id: 837838, observation_id: 837838, is_parent: False, is_child: True
# ID: 837909, parent_id: 837838, observation_id: 837838, is_parent: False, is_child: True
```

Following the logic, I'd expect to see the parent (`id=837838`) being returned in the last two queries above, but it's not. If this was not a self-referential model, I *think(?)* this would work for distinct parent/child classes, but in this case it does not.

How do I obtain the same functionality for the class expression `@is_parent.expression` as for the instance hybrid_property of `is_parent` and make the `is_parent` and `object_id` properties queryable?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd post an answer with the current best workable solution. This is based on an improved version of the extremely helpful answer provided by @|159. A current workable solution to the is_parent expression is:

```py
@is_parent.expression
def is_parent(cls):
    parent_ids = [i[0] for i in db.session.query(cls.parent_id).filter(cls.parent_id.isnot(None)).distinct().all()]
    return cls.id.in_(parent_ids)
```

This has the improvement of filtering null parents and only returning a distinct list of parent_ids to test with the `.in_` condition, as opposed to testing the `.in_` condition against millions of null values including duplicates, which worked, but was infeasibly slow.

At the moment, this appears to operate suitably quickly for the size of the dataset with very few parents, but if the list of parents grows very large (which it could in theory), I imagine this could get slow again. I'm posting this to summarise the best working solution thus far as food for thought in the hopes that someone can offer a better more scalable method.

### EDIT

The performance of this solution is not great and is resulting in significant query delays on the model even when not filtering on those properties, so I've had to deactivate the `is_parent` and `observation_id` hybrid_properties. I defined a non-hybrid property and modified my query to side-step the performance issues:

```
@property
def observation_id(self):
    return self.parent_id if self.is_child else self.id if self.children.count()>0 else None
```

And can query members of the same observation group by querying `or_(AnnotationLabel.id==self.observation_id,AnnotationLabel.parent_id==self.observation_id)`. Not ideal or elegant - this approach results in some limitations on the types of queries I was hoping to be able to make, so I'll accept better answers if there are any.

Comment: if you think that an answer is helpful or solved your issue, you can upvote or/and accept the answer. This is how Stackoverflow rating works. Also, you can accept your own answer if it is the most relevant.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to accept it as answered, in case someone offered a better solution, but I'm not sure that there is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

#### The workable `is_parent` expression class method:

```
@is_parent.expression                                                  
def is_parent(cls):                                                    
    parent_ids = db.session.execute(select([cls.parent_id])).fetchall()
    return cls.id.in_([i[0] for i in parent_ids])
```

The type of the object that you have to return form the expression class method is `sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression` that provides boolean comparison results accordingly to the entries. In this way, to use `count` was a wrong assumption.

#### EDIT

The main difference between the original solution and the one I made is the nature of the query result. `.scalar() > 0` on the result of `count` is a single boolean value. A query passed to `filter` (reach comparison) must return a boolean for each element because filtering in it essence is binary masking of table content.

---

*Nice question, btw! Well defined!*

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Interesting approach - it works, but doing a fetchall on the whole table seems to be too slow to be practical. The table has millions of rows and evaluating the parent_id expression in this way takes minutes on the current table (which is growing continuously). Are there any other, more efficient approaches that may work?

Comment: @Ari , that was my main concern about the implementation. I'll think about it.

Comment: @Ari , No-no, the problem is `.scalar() > 0` returns True, the result of the query is a single boolean. To provide filtering you need a query that returns boolean value per entry. If you have a million entries, the query must return a million booleans. That why I don't think there is an efficient solution significantly different from the one I made.

Comment: To add to the discussion: 

`db.session.execute(db.select([func.count(AnnotationLabel.id)]).where(AnnotationLabel.parent_id==837838)).scalar() > 0` 
returns **True** as expected, and 

`type(db.select([func.count(AnnotationLabel.id)]).where(AnnotationLabel.parent_id==837838).as_scalar()>0)`
is a: **sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression**

The approach I originally tried above seems to work when parent/child classes are distinct and not self-referential. Eg the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13642708/11095676)

Comment: Sorry @|159, I couldn't edit my previous comment after 5 minutes, so I had to delete it, but your answer above then is still relevant. The scalar evaluation would still be very slow based on the size of the dataset... hmmm... I'm hoping there's some way to crack this!

Comment: Ok, after some fiddling around with your suggestion, this speeds it up dramatically:
`db.session.execute(db.select([cls.parent_id]).where(cls.parent_id.isnot(None))).fetchall()`. At the moment, most records have null parent_ids. But that may start to grow in the future which will slow this down again, but for the time-being, this seems to be a workable solution... I'm keen to explore other options (if they exist) I'll leave this unanswered for now in the hopes that there may be other elegant ways to solve this.

Comment: @Ari, I slightly improved your latest idea. Please see the updated answer. Please try it on your database with profiling. I believe the performance problem is still there.

Comment: @|159, firstly thanks for the effort and thought on this. The latest suggestion using `return cls.parent_id.isnot(None)` does not work, since it is the test for is_child. That is exactly what the `@is_child.expression` does (and I have confirmed that works properly). If you meant is(None) instead of isnot(None), that also wouldn't work because the complexity comes in that parent_id is nullable, so having a null `parent_id` does not mean that it is a parent, it just means that it's not a child.

Comment: @Ari, yeah, you are right. I'm removing the edit to avoid confusions. Thanks for the clarification.